# Controller spec failing to find routes defined by my Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rspec-rails, rails-engines

I'm building a Rails engine under Rails 3.0.12, but **I'm having issues with routes when trying to write specs for my engine's controller.**

### The context

I've been following an [Enginex](https://github.com/josevalim/enginex) layout. The engine is named `Featuring` and is not *isolated*. It does not declare routes by itself: there is no `featuring/config/routes.rb` file. Instead, a `routes_for_feature` method is provided for the main application to define engine-specific routes.

```
##
# featuring/lib/featuring/rails.rb
#
require 'featuring/rails/routing'

module Featuring
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end

##
# featuring/lib/featuring/rails/routing.rb
#
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper

    def routes_for_feature(feature_name)
      resource_name = feature_name.to_s.pluralize.to_sym
      resources resource_name, :controller => "featuring/features", :only => [:index, :show], :feature => feature_name.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Following the Enginex template, I have a `Dummy` app which define the routes as so:

```
# featuring/spec/dummy/config/routes.rb
Dummy::Application.routes.draw do
  routes_for_feature :feature_model
end
```

### The issue

**Everything is working fine when I run the rails server for the `Dummy` app**. I can browse to `http://localhost:3000/feature_models` and the request is successful.

**I would like to spec my `Featuring::FeaturesController`, but I can't get it to find the routes.**

Here is the spec:

```
# featuring/spec/controllers/features_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Featuring::FeaturesController do

  context "feature_models" do
    it "GET index should be successful" do
      puts Rails.application.routes.routes
      get :index, { :use_route => "featuring", :feature => "feature_models" }
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the result of running this spec:

```
rspec spec/controllers/features_controller_spec.rb:7
Featuring::FeaturesController
  feature_models
GET    /feature_models(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"featuring/features"}
GET    /feature_models/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"featuring/features"}
    GET index should be successful (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Featuring::FeaturesController feature_models GET index should be successful
     Failure/Error: get :index, { :use_route => "featuring", :feature => "feature_models" }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:feature=>"feature_models", :controller=>"featuring/features"}
     # ./spec/controllers/features_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**As you can see, even if the routes are correctly defined, the spec'ed controller seems not to find them.**

Something surprises me in the `RoutingError`: `No route matches {:feature=>"feature_models", :controller=>"featuring/features"}`. **The `action => "index"` is not displayed.**

Comment: I'm having this issue as well in rails 3.2.3. I know for sure that it's not related to :action => "index", but I'm still stumped as to why I'm getting this RoutingError...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and I was also confused by the lack of {:action => "index"} in the route options. However, this turned out not to be the problem. ActionDispatch treats the lack of an :action as equivalent to {:action => "index"}. See:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L545

You may be missing a request parameter in your spec, as was the case with me. Check the Parameters line in your server log when you load the page in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add `routes { }` to your spec, like so:

```
describe Featuring::FeaturesController do
  routes { Featuring::Engine.routes }
  # ...
end
```

See also [No Route Matches ... Rails Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924752/no-route-matches-rails-engine)