# No Route Matches ... Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

So I keep getting the error:

`No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"xaaron/api_keys"}`

Which is thrown in the test:

```
it "should not create an api key for those not logged in" do
  post :create
  expect(response).to redirect_to xaaron.login_path
end
```

when I go to `spec/dummy` and run the `rake routes` command I see:

```
       api_keys GET    /api_keys(.:format)                 xaaron/api_keys#index
                POST   /api_keys(.:format)                 xaaron/api_keys#create
    new_api_key GET    /api_keys/new(.:format)             xaaron/api_keys#new
   edit_api_key GET    /api_keys/:id/edit(.:format)        xaaron/api_keys#edit
        api_key GET    /api_keys/:id(.:format)             xaaron/api_keys#show
                PATCH  /api_keys/:id(.:format)             xaaron/api_keys#update
                PUT    /api_keys/:id(.:format)             xaaron/api_keys#update
                DELETE /api_keys/:id(.:format)             xaaron/api_keys#destroy
```

Which shows that yes this route does exist. My routes file for this engine looks like:

```
Xaaron::Engine.routes.draw do
      get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'login'
      get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
      get 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => 'signup'
      get 'permission_denied' => 'error#denied', :as => 'permission_denied'
      get 'record_not_found' => 'error#error', :as => 'record_not_found'
      get 'password_reset' => 'password_resets#edit', :as => 'rest_user_password'

      resource :error, controller: 'error'

      resources :users
      resources :api_keys
      resources :sessions
      resources :roles
      resources :password_resets
end
```

What am I missing?

## update

For those of you curious how I am getting these routes, its because the dummy app's routes file is set up (by default) as such:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount Xaaron::Engine => "/xaaron"
end
```

## Update II

I have been reading [this api docs on how routing is done in engines](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) and I believe the way I have done this is correct, how ever the controller is defined as such:

```
module Xaaron
  class ApiKeysController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
      @api_key = Xaaron::ApiKey.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end

    def create
      @api_key = Xaaron::ApiKey.new(:user_id => current_user.id, :api_key => SecureRandom.hex(16))
      create_api_key(@api_key)
    end

    def destroy
      Xaaron::ApiKey.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:notice] = 'Api Key has been deleted.'
      redirect_to xarron.api_keys_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will do little bit of research on `mount`. How is `api_keys` controller defined? Is it within module `xaaron`? Please share some specific details/ code.

Comment: @KirtiThorat appropriate updates have been made. as stated I have also been reading: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html to better understand how routes work in engines specifically. and I believe I have done this correctly - although I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to tell your spec you are using the engine routes:

```
describe ApiKeysController do
  routes { Xaaron::Engine.routes }

  it "should not create an api key for those not logged in" do
    post :create
    expect(response).to redirect_to xaaron.login_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Really? Is their documentation on that some where?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/routing-specs/engine-routes

Comment: +1 That was quite simple!! I didn't know about this. :p

Comment: This works in controller specs too (in addition to the routing specs in the docs that @LoganSerman linked to): https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/controller-specs/engine-routes-for-controllers